# Upload contents of current html page from a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

What would be a good way to upload the html content of the current page viewed in the browser to another server from a bookmarklet?

Assuming this url is on a server that requires authentication, so I want to avoid fetching the page on the sever side, but rather would like to see if it's possible to get the contents and upload them directly from within the browser.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Elisha

Answer (score -2):

Considering that you are most probably going to have a situation in which the page being viewed in the browser is on a different domain from the domain you want to send the data to, an AJAX request will definitely fail (due to Cross-Domain restrictions). So doing this server side would be your best bet.

Answer (score -2):

1. Retrieve `location.href` with `XHR` into string
2. Create `FORM` with desired cross-site action
3. `POST` data to server
4. ?????
5. PROFIT!